# How to install macOS 14 Sonoma or 13 Ventura on an external partition

Tags: macos, installation

I would like to install macOS 14 Sonoma on an external partition, but I couldn't find an installer on the developer website. It seems that it's only possible to upgrade from the System Settings, so I thought I would install Ventura first on the separate partition and then upgrade to Sonoma.

I downloaded the Ventura installer from the App Store and selected the external partition during the installation, but when the Mac reboots, it just reboots into my main macOS partition. If I shut down and hold the power button pressed to select the boot partition (I have a M1 MacBook Pro 14" 2022), then nothing happens: an indeterminate progress indicator spins for a couple seconds, the partition list remains there and I can only successfully boot into my main partition again. I also tried running the installer from another macOS Ventura and macOS Monterey partition I had installed last year, but when I select the partition on which to install the new Ventura, nothing happens and I can only quit the installer.

Is there a way to debug all these issues? How can I install macOS Sonoma on a separate partition without overwriting my main macOS Ventura install?